# Add-PnPFile fails with "Access denied"

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, access-denied, sharepoint-permissions

I'm trying below code to add File to Site Pages -

`Add-PnPFile -Path 'C:\Temp\myfile.aspx' -Folder "SitePages"`
but getting **"Access denied"** .

I have checked permissions for my user under `https://acme.sharepoint.com/sites/my-site/_layouts/15/user.aspx` and found that my user gets the **"Deny Add and Customize Pages"** message, which probably explains why I'm not allowed to run the `Add-PnPFile` command.

Why I am getting the `Deny Add and Customize Pages` message is what's puzzling me, though.

I've created a permission level called `admin permissions` in which every permission (including `Add and Customize Pages`) is checked, and created a group `admins` which use that permission level. I've added myself to that group, and made sure I'm not a member of any other groups (i.e. "Owners", "Members", "Visitors") on that site.

So why do I still get the "Access denied" error message when running `Add-PnPFile`? In my (powershell) script I've also added `Set-SPOSite -Identity <path/to/site> -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $false` but still no luck.

Any help in debugging this will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you a site collection administrator for this? Or site owner? Try using these accounts once.

Comment: @GaneshSanap, thanks for your input. I've verified that I'm indeed a site admin for the site in question.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have enabled **custom script** at **tenant** level via `Classic SharePoint admin center > settings > Custom Script` or via this link:

`https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/TenantSettings.aspx`

[image]

It may take up to 24 hours for this setting to take effect in your tenant. Make sure you log in as a global admin.

Answer (score 1):

This command did the trick for me:

```
Set-SPOsite <SiteURL> -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

Here, `0` means it's allowed.

Comment: Thanks. Did you need to enable custom script at tenant level, as suggested by https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/281728/84750?

Comment: Late reply but Yeah I enabled it